# Scrape stock data from subpages of a website without change of address

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Based on [Ingo Janßen german tutorial](https://ingo-janssen.de/web-scraping-in-5-schritten-automatisiert-daten-sammeln/) I wrote a web scraper to scrape data from boerse.de-webpage.
My function should return the links of all SP500 stocks of that page into a `pandas` data:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests
import pickle
import numpy as np
import re

##
# Loads stock basic information into a pandas dataframe
##

def load_stocks_sp500():
    response = requests.get(
        "https://www.boerse.de/realtime-kurse/SundP-500-Aktien/US78378X1072")

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'pushList'})
    body = table.find('tbody')

    stocks = body.find_all('tr')
    data = {}

    for stock in stocks:
        try:
            isin = stock['id']
            div = stock.find('div', {'class': 'tablesorter N'})
            link = div.find('a')
            data[isin] = {
                'Name': link.text,
                'URL': link['href']
            }
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments: {1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.transpose()
    df.index.name = 'ISIN'
    #df.to_csv(f'Webscrapper/Boerse/{filename}_summary.csv')

    return df
```

The page itself is classified into 17 subpages.

[image]

With the code above I only get the first subpage. Is there a modification to collect the data of all 17 subpages together?

Comment: Yes sure there is a way! Look in the elements inspector in the network tab, there you will be able to see which requests the site makes, in this case, the page requests to https://www.boerse.de/ajax/table.php via POST request. Try and play with the requests parameters and reprogram your script to work with these requests instead of the whole site. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is retrieved via POST request. The tutorial gets you the initial one, but they don't show how to go from there. Look at this and you can see how that works:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.boerse.de/ajax/table.php'

payload = {
'LISTID': 'US78378X1072@16',
'K_SORTCOLUM': 'N',
'K_SORTORDER': 'asc',
'K_PAGE_SIZE': '30'}

page = 0
results = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    payload['K_PAGE'] = str(page)
    print('Page: %s' %(page+1))
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
    df = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])
    df = df[df['Unnamed: 0'].isnull()].drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
    
    if len(df) == 0:
        print('Finished.')
        break
    
    results = results.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    page+=1
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
                     Name    Bid    Ask   Akt.  ... Tagesvol. Vortag      Zeit Börse
0              3M Company  15625  15660  15643  ...       NaN  15370  14:39:13   LSR
1              A.O. Smith   7186   7300   7243  ...       NaN   7167  14:13:52   LSR
2         Abbott Champion  11175  11215  11195  ...       NaN  11083  14:37:07   LSR
3                  Abbvie  10408  10430  10419  ...       NaN  10260  14:41:41   LSR
4                 Abiomed  29260  29530  29395  ...       NaN  28915  14:41:53   LSR
..                    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...       ...    ...       ...   ...
497  Yum! Brands Champion  11155  11200  11178  ...       NaN  10963  14:53:58   LSR
498    Zebra Technologies  53000  53620  53310  ...       NaN  52330  14:54:01   LSR
499       Zimmer Holdings  11245  11305  11275  ...       NaN  11118  14:50:51   LSR
500  Zions Bancorporation   5700   5750   5725  ...       NaN   5625  14:47:18   LSR
501                Zoetis  19585  19685  19635  ...       NaN  19100  14:53:56   LSR

[502 rows x 13 columns]
```